# Peak locations in Hz with findpeaks() (log spaced bins)

Tags: filters, frequency-response, octave

I have resolved peak locations using Octave [`findpeaks`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/findpeaks.html) command:

```
[pks, idx] = findpeaks(totalmag,"DoubleSided");
semilogx(nf,totalmag,nf(idx),totalmag(idx),'ok', 'linewidth', 2);
```

where `totalmag` holds logaritmically spaced magnitude response sum of 18 peak filters. Magnitude of each filter is got with ***bode*** command:

```
nf = logspace(0, 5, fs/2);

[mag, pha, w] = bode(flt,2*pi*nf);
```

and is summed as:

```
totalmag = totalmag .+ 20*log10(abs(mag));
```

[image]

I would like to convert `idx` values to frequency values so that `idx(1)` points to 55 Hz etc.
Now `idx(1)` holds value 7690 which points to ~55 Hz (`totalmag(idx(1))` = 7.629dB as seen in plot).
I guess this is related to logarithmic scale used in plot but, have not found any resolution for conversion.

Can this conversion be done and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For logarithmically-spaced bins:
$$f_k = Ae^{(\log(B)-\log(A))*k/N}$$

where

- $N$ is the number of frequency bins
- $A$ and $B$ are the start and end frequencies in your log-spaced array of frequencies
- $k = 0 \dots N-1$ is the bin number
- $f_k$ (in $\tt{Hz}$) is where bin $k$ starts

For example, with your specifications:

```
f = 10^0 * exp((log(10^5)-log(10^0))*7676/(44100/2))
f = 55.0287
```

---

For linearly-spaced bins:
$$f_k = k \frac{f_s}{N_{\texttt{FFT}}}$$
where $f_k$ is the frequency in $\texttt{Hz}$, $k$ the bin number, $f_s$ the sampling frequency and $N_{\texttt{FFT}}$ the FFT length.

Comment: @JuhaP, I think this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Yes, I saw that equation somewhere but, understood `e` meaning 2.71828... :( .

Comment: That's indeed the case that $e = 2.718 \dots$. It's a constant. You can replace `exp(...)` by `2.718 ^ (...)` (with loss of precision obviously).